# How do I move specific rows into new columns based on a condition

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with the following format:

| time | emg | eda |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Stimulus 80 | NA | NA |
| NA | NA | NA |
| Onset time | MAX (ch4) | MAX (ch7) |
| 131.84450000000001 | 8.6929632579550682 | 7.8114367391085029 |
| 142.83000000000001 | 2.062198261793945 | 9.0520476734366273 |
| 150.60149999999999 | 2.8645742403188507 | 8.6158402220299344 |
| NA | NA | NA |
| Stimulus 10 | NA | NA |
| NA | NA | NA |
| Onset time | MAX (ch4) | MAX (ch7) |
| 134.25999999999999 | 1.4936528696982108 | 8.6331626452321366 |

This table goes on for about 10 more stimuli, and the amount of rows per stimulus is variable. Is there a way in which I can move the rows that belong to specific stimuli to new columns? I want to do it in such a way that if I get another one of these dataframes, that I can run the code again and format the table without having to check how many rows each stimulus has.

The way I want the table to be formatted is going to be like this:

| time | emg80 | eda80 | emg10 | eda10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 131.84450000000001 | 8.6929632579550682 | 7.8114367391085029 | NA | NA |
| 134.25999999999999 | NA | NA | 1.4936528696982108 | 8.6331626452321366 |
| 142.83000000000001 | 2.062198261793945 | 9.0520476734366273 | NA | NA |
| 150.60149999999999 | 2.8645742403188507 | 8.6158402220299344 | NA | NA |

I don't even know if this is possible, but I'd really appreciate anyone who can help me out somewhat.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please follow the following link and include a reproducible example in your question with proper formatting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant way... using reshape2

```
df=structure(list(time = c("Stimulus 80", NA, "Onset time", "131.84450000000001", 
"142.83000000000001", "150.60149999999999", NA, "Stimulus 10", 
NA, "Onset time", "134.25999999999999"), emg = c(NA, NA, "MAX (ch4)", 
"8.6929632579550682", "2.062198261793945", "2.8645742403188507", 
NA, NA, NA, "MAX (ch4)", "1.4936528696982108"), eda = c(NA, NA, 
"MAX (ch7)", "7.8114367391085029", "9.0520476734366273", "8.6158402220299344", 
NA, NA, NA, "MAX (ch7)", "8.6331626452321366")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))

library(reshape2)

df1=melt(
  df,
  id.vars="time",
  measure.vars=c("emg","eda")
)

tmp=grepl("Stimulus",df1$time)

df1$g=cumsum(tmp)

df1=merge(
  df1,
  setNames(
    df1[tmp,c("time","g")],
    c("name","g")
  ),
  by="g",
  all=T
)

df1$name=paste0(
  df1$variable,
  sapply(strsplit(df1$name," "),"[[",2)
)

dcast(
  df1[grepl("^\\d+",df1$time),],
  time~name,
  value.var="value"
)
```

resulting in

```
                time              eda10              eda80              emg10              emg80
1 131.84450000000001               <NA> 7.8114367391085029               <NA> 8.6929632579550682
2 134.25999999999999 8.6331626452321366               <NA> 1.4936528696982108               <NA>
3 142.83000000000001               <NA> 9.0520476734366273               <NA>  2.062198261793945
4 150.60149999999999               <NA> 8.6158402220299344               <NA> 2.8645742403188507
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This has definitely helped me :)